# How to access the name of composed objects?

Tags: javascript, object, reflection

Consider the following Javascript object:

```
thing1 = {'fp1': [{'dp1a': 0}, {'dp1b': 1}], 'fp2': [{'dp2a': 2}, {'dp2b': 3}]}
```

I would like to craft a function `showPath()`that works according to the following example:

```
thing1.fp1.dp1a.showPath()
```

`showPath()` should return the cascaded keys of the calling object, in the example:
`thing1`, `fp1`, and `dp1a`.

How to craft the `showPath()` method?

Comment: do you really want to call the function inside of the object?

Comment: In order to call that function you already _know_ the path.

Comment: do you want to split a string by '.'

Comment: @Andy: I want to fetch the path in the function showPath().

Comment: @NinaScholz: The idea is to avoid something like thing1.showPath(['fp1', 'dp1a']), if this is was what you suggested.